# Tracking PHP function calls using php-cpp

Tags: php, php-cpp

I am writing a PHP extension using php-cpp to help me profile my code.

Is there any way in php-cpp to track all calls to a specific function without modifying my php?

e.g. track all calls to json_encode() and get the arguments being passed to it?

Like javascript, maybe can I register a callback function on the event of a json_encode call? *just groping in the dark here*

Would be great if someone who has experience with php-cpp can point in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not take a look at how xdebug does it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.